# ValueChangeEvent not firing when values are returned

Tags: java, jsf, valuechangelistener

In my jsf page I have a inputtext field and a hidden field. I have an edit button and upon clicking the edit button a popup screen appears and I selects a value and selected value returns back to my hidden field.

I added a valueChangeListener to my hidden field and added the following code in my bean.

```
public void processChange(ValueChangeEvent event){        
    try  {           
        logger.info("event new value "+event.getNewValue().toString());

    } catch (Exception ex)  {                        
    }
```

However every time when I change value using the edit popup window and returns value back to my hidden field, valueChangeListener is not firing I guess.

Any idea why valueChangeListener is not firing? My page scope is session and using JSF 1.1.

Idea behind this approach is to re-query and based on values from popup, I would like refresh data in JSF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not catch at first the most superclass Exception and especially without logging anything. Maybe your object from event.getNewValue() is null, then you get a NullPointerException and you don't will be noticed about that.

Use something like that:

```
public void processChange(ValueChangeEvent event){        
try  {           
    logger.info("event new value "+event.getNewValue().toString());

} catch (NullPointerException ex)  { 
     logger.error("object is null: "+ex.getMessage());              
} catch (Exception ex)  { 
     logger.error(ex);              
}
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: -@timaschew I changed the exception part like you mentioned, still I am not able to see the changed value in my bean. valueChangeListener is not firing I guess

Comment: @BalusC could your provide some insight?

Comment: try the [PropertyChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)

Comment: -@timaschew there is no PropertyChangeListener for inputText component in JSF 1.1 I guess.

Comment: hmm okay, I don't know about JSF, try to google some stuff [ValueChangeEvent+JSF](http://www.google.com/search?q=ValueChangeEvent+JSF)

Answer (score 1):

you have to submit the form.
Add an onchage attribute in the tag which calls a javascript which submits the form. 
Until the form is submitted value changeevent wont be called.